# Oracle Sql CASE statement returning data based on row count

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select one id in my query as orderid which is based on a condition.
If it is present in another table ode with condition parentid=childid. then i should return that child id. Else i will be picking the id from another table ml

For that i have written this query and is returning data as expected.

```
 CASE
      WHEN (SELECT COUNT(childid) FROM ode WHERE ode.parentid= ode.childid)>0
          THEN CAST((SELECT ode.childid FROM ode WHERE ode.parentid= ode.childid) AS VARCHAR(100))
      ELSE ml.someotherID
 END  AS orderid
```

Is there any better way to rewrite this query? instead of repeating the select statement again (once for count and then for value)

Comment: Can you show some data sample? And from it what would be the desired result? Hard to understand what you want with just PART of the query.

Comment: I know its hard with just a part of the query. but its part of a big query..and with lots of tables.

Comment: Won't this query fail when you get more than one matching record in ode? Moreover I think you have a typo: the subquery is not correlated to the main query, because all criteria in `ode.parentid= ode.childid` refers to the inner table. (You are merely counting ode records with parentid = childid).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it is better to put such logic in the `from` clause rather than in the `select` clause.  However, without the rest of the query, it is hard to see whether that it the best method.

For your approach, you should use `exists` rather than `select count()` in the subquery:

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ode WHERE ode.parentid = ode.childid)
      THEN (SELECT CAST(ode.childid as VARCHAR2(100) FROM ode WHERE ode.parentid = ode.childid) )
      ELSE ml.someotherID
 END) AS orderid
```

You could also simplify this to `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE( (SELECT CAST(ode.childid as VARCHAR2(100) FROM ode WHERE ode.parentid = ode.childid) ),  ml.someotherID)
```

Note:  Oracle prefers `varchar2()` to `varchar()`, so you should use that unless you have a good reason for not using it.